# Alternative to iconv encoding utf-8-mac

Tags: terminal, encoding, utf-8

There used to be support for an encoding option called `utf-8-mac` with `iconv` in the Terminal. It's mentioned in this forum several times. I used to use it a lot. Now with the following command (that used to work):

```
iconv -f utf-8-mac -t CP1252 infile.m3u > outfile.m3u
```

I get:

```
iconv: conversion to utf-8-mac unsupported
```

I tried an encoding called `mac` but that does not work either.

A clumpsy workaround in my case is to open in TextEdit, duplicate and save using `Windows Latin 1` encoding. But I'd really prefer using iconv, but I don't know what to look for and there are many encodings. Is there an equivalent to `utf-8-mac`?

Currently I use: macOS 10.14.6

Comment: Have you tried another input file? utf to a simple code page might not work in all cases if there are unicode characters that can't be converted

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean, iconv itself says `utf-8-mac` is unsupported. Using `utf-8` does not work if that's what you mean.

Comment: There can be things in a utf file that cannot be converted to a code page. iconv then errors out with a message. So I think there is something in your input file that cannot be converted.

Comment: Also the command line says the input is utf-8-mac but the error message says that is the output - are you sure you have the correct error message and command line

Comment: Yes, that's a strange error message but I get the same with any made upp rubish-encoding name. The line following says `iconv: try 'iconv -l' to get the list of supported encodings` and utf-8-mac is not listed, so it's definitely gone as an option. Perhaps also I didn't make it clear this used to work with similar file using `utf-8-mac` so I need to find an alternative doing the same thing. I still have files with this encoding.

Comment: What does `which iconv` show as Montereys iconv and the macports versions on iconv -l both have a line 'UTF-8-MAC UTF8-MAC'

Comment: Ah, yes now I understand. I have a less than ideal Pythoninstallation with Anaconda and those paths are searched before `/usr/bin/`where my usual ìconv`is. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The order in my `PATH` variable didn't point to the most current and/or adequate version of `iconv`.

After making sure I use the version found in `/usr/bin/` everything works as expected (as pointed out by @mmmmmm).